# How can I use PromptDialog.Choice while allowing the user to type the options without worrying about accented letters?

Tags: bots, botframework

How can I use PromptDialog.Choice while allowing the user to type the options without worrying about accented letters?

Given the following prompt to the user:

```
List<string> promptValues = new List<string> { "Sim", "Não" };

PromptDialog.Choice<string>(context,
                AfterPrompt,
                promptValues,
                "Digite 'Sim' ou 'Não'",
                "Opção inválida, por favor tente novamente.");
```

How can I allow the user to input "Nao" or "Não" without the prompt considering "Nao" as a wrong answer?

I can't use PromptDialog.Confirm because I need the dialogs to happen in Portuguese, and as far as I know I can't localize PromptDialog.Choice.

Also I want to know how can I ignore accents even with other kinds of prompt, not only Yes or No prompts.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you might be able to localize the `PromptConfirm` options if you change the culture of the bot like:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE");
```

because the options are being retrieved from a resource file (see [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L441))

Now, [it seems](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Resource) that the Portuguese resource is not implemented yet, which from my point of view it could be something great to contribute if you want to.

On the other hand, if you want to have some custom logic in the `PromptChoice`, you can always inherit from it and override the `TryParse` method to add your checks. Here is an example of a [custom PromptChoice](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-Search/Search.Dialogs/CancelablePromptChoice.cs).